# How to prove this inequality $\sqrt{2x^2-6x+5}+\sqrt{y^2-4y+5}+\sqrt{2x^2-2xy+y^2}\ge \sqrt{10}$

Tags: calculus, inequality

Let $x,y\in R$, show that
$$\sqrt{2x^2-6x+5}+\sqrt{y^2-4y+5}+\sqrt{2x^2-2xy+y^2}\ge \sqrt{10}$$

Comment: Try squaring the whole thing, then that is larger than sum of square of each terms. See if you find anything?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

1. $\sqrt{2x^2-6x+5}= \sqrt{(x-1)^2+(x-2)^2}$ is the distance from $A(1,2)$ to $B(x,x)$.
2. $\sqrt{2x^2-2xy+y^2}=\sqrt{(x-y)^2+x^2}$ is the distance from $B(x,x)$ to $C(y,0)$.
3. $\sqrt{y^2-4y+5}=\sqrt{(y-2)^2+(-1)^2 }$ is the distance from $C(y,0)$ to $D(2,-1)$.

The inequality is then equivalent to
$$AB+BC+CD\ge AD.$$

Comment: Perfect answer.  One vote for you. How can you come up with the idea?

Comment: @Mr.VN I don't know, just the first thing that comes to mind when seeing the inequality of the form $\sqrt{\phantom{x}}+\sqrt{\phantom{x}}+\cdots$.